# From where can I get the Braintree HTTP client Java classes?

Tags: java, paypal, braintree

I am trying to verify a PayPal Checkout transaction with the REST API from Java according to this example: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#6-verify-the-transaction

In the server side Java example the classes `com.braintreepayments.http.HttpResponse` and `com.braintreepayments.http.serializer.Json` are used. I cannot find a Maven repository or otherwise official source for these. Is there an official/recommended way to obtain these classes?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with the PayPal documentation, I did some research using the class names and I found the checkout SDK that they use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.checkout.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>checkout-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

The version that they provide is RC2. We will need to wait for the stable one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Joe7 could you Mark as the correct answer if that helped you?